# Understanding recursive solution to Towers of Hanoi

Tags: c, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Can anybody please explain this program? I especially want to know how the parameters are passed to the function `tower` and how the recursion works.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
  int n;
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter the no. of disks");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  tower(n,'S','D','T');
  getch();
}

tower(int n,char SOURCE,char DEST,char TEMP)
{
  if(n>0)
  {
    tower(n-1,SOURCE,TEMP,DEST);
    printf("\nMove disk %d from %c to %c",n,SOURCE,DEST);
    tower(n-1,TEMP,DEST,SOURCE);
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be a lot less confusing if it was indented -_-

Comment: Recursion isn't as confusing as recursion isn't as confusing as recursion isn't as confusing as...

Comment: This is the canonical recursive solution to the Towers of Hanoi problem: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/survey/recurse/hanoiimpl.html

Comment: recursive, *adj*: See *recursive*

Comment: @SubSevn you beat me to the exact same comment... :)

Comment: If I am not asking for too much, How does the program work in general?

Comment: Take paper and pencil and start executing program yourself. Or use debugger to step by step execution and see variable values.

Comment: @Rohan I tried but I cannot understand

Comment: @BoydSmith, then ask some specific question.

Comment: @BoydSmith the link that SubSevn provided contains an explanation

Comment: @Rohan Ok. How does the program work from if(n>0). Like how the variables are stored in stack

Comment: @Hulk I perfectly understand Tower of henoi. All I want to know is how the program works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program illustrates the solution for Tower of Hanoi problem.

So you have pile 1 with n disks and 2 other empty pile 2 and 3. You will need to move n disks from pile 1 to pile 3(or 1 to 2, it does not matter).

If you imagine n disks as (n-1 disks) and 1 disk, the problem becomes simple: move (n-1) to pile 2 and the last disk to pile 3.

So now you need to work out how to move (n-1) disks from pile 1 to pile 2, which means you have the exact problem with n-1 disks. Repeat the process and eventually you'll get to the point that you only need to move 1 disk from pile 1 to pile 2.

Comment: I want to add something: The output of the recursive solution for the Tower of Hanoi problem is a set of instructions on how to solve the problem in real life. Look for a video on the internet about the real-life problem and you will get what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the best way to explain is to start by explaining how you do it in real life: To move N disks,

- First you move N-1 disks to the intermediate position,
- Then you move the bottom disk to the destination,
- Finally you move the N-1 disks from the intermediate position to the destination.

The code mimics that. The only thing to understand is that the "roles" of source, destination and temporary are different for the sub-towers.

- When I say "move N-1 from source to temp", it means `source2 = source`, `dest2 = temp`, and as a consequence `temp2 = dest`.
- When you move the bottom disk, all is unchanged ( `source3 = source`, `dest3 = dest`, `temp3 = temp`
- When I say "move N-1 from temp to dest", it means `source4 = temp`, `dest4 = dest`, and as a consequence `temp4 = source`.